# how to get certain values from a dataframe column based on position

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Please suggest on how to handle the below scenario.

Below is the dataframe.

```
            0    1
```

AAAXXXX08/26/2020
ABC0000000001PPPP TEST
ABC0000000002PPPP TEST
ABC0000000003PPPP TEST
ABC0000000004PPPP TEST
ABC0000000005PPPP TEST
ABC0000000006PPPP TEST

how can we extract only the value '08/26/2020' from the dataframe and assign to a variable when the record in the dataframe starts with 'AAA'?.

I would like to extract the date '08/26/2020' based on the position (as I am aware of the position of the date field). Not sure if it's possible.

Currently, I am taking the below approach.

- Selecting the record matching the criteria (starts with AAA) and writing to a file.
- Then reading the same file and utilizing slicing to get the required data.

Thanks

Comment: Just omit writing to file, instead slice it there only

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way with the `.extract()` method:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''idx  data
0   AAAXXXX08/26/2020
1  ABC0000000001PPPP TEST
2  ABC0000000002PPPP TEST
3  ABC0000000003PPPP TEST
4  ABC0000000004PPPP TEST
5  ABC0000000005PPPP TEST
6  ABC0000000006PPPP TEST'''

# create data frame
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')

# pull out date, if line starts with 'AAA' and ends with date in mm/dd/yyyy format:
df['new_date'] = (df['data'].str.extract(r'AAA.*(\d+/\d+/\d+)')
                            .astype('datetime64[D]'))

# results
print(df)

   idx                    data   new_date
0    0       AAAXXXX08/26/2020 2020-08-26
1    1  ABC0000000001PPPP TEST        NaT
2    2  ABC0000000002PPPP TEST        NaT
3    3  ABC0000000003PPPP TEST        NaT
4    4  ABC0000000004PPPP TEST        NaT
5    5  ABC0000000005PPPP TEST        NaT
6    6  ABC0000000006PPPP TEST        NaT
```